# RedGate SQL Source Control GIT commit error?

Tags: git, redgate

Trying to set up SQL Management Studio to work with GIT do everything according to instructions. But the commit fails,

An error: 
Command: 
git add "Tables \ dbo.Table_3.sql" "CommandLineHooks.xml"

Output: 
"git" Ґ pў "pҐvbp ўgvaҐҐ © E" E ўҐiҐ ©

Є®¬ ¤® ©, ЁbЇ® "pҐ¬® © Їa®Јa ¬¬® © E" E ¯ d ЄҐvl¬ © «®¬.

Exit code: 
1

What could be the problem? 
I think you need to configure the user name to connect to the GIT. But where it can be sdleat?

Answer (score 0):

is there a chance you can produce the error so that the characters don't get converted? There must be a unicode/cyrillic/god knows issue going on to make the error unreadable.

It could be:

git binary has not been added to the %PATH%

some other gitty thing